# Error C2659 in C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to this and to programming in C++

I keep getting the error Errors:    1   error C2659: '=' : function as left operand W:\CGT 215\Final Project\game\game\paddle.cpp   11  1   game

2   IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue    w:\CGT 215\Final Project\game\game\paddle.cpp   11  2   game

```
#include "Paddle.h"
#include <iostream>


Paddle::Paddle(int width, int height, float (*Controller)())
{
    m_position.x = 100;
    m_position.y = 100;
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
    Control = Controller;
}

void Paddle::Update() 
{
    m_position.y += *Control();
}
```

Comment: Your question highly relates to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565790/c-pointer-to-a-function-in-struct

Answer (score 0):

Given the error code, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t03ksxc.aspx), `Control` seems to be an existing function and not a function pointer hence cannot be assigned. You want to define another field to hold the function pointer.

Here a code sample to do that:

```
struct Paddle
{
    float (*Control)();
    ...

    Paddle(int width, int height, float (*Controller)());
    void Update();
};
```

Then, your `Update` implementation should not dereference the `Control` function pointer:

```
void Paddle::Update() 
{
    m_position.y += Control();
}
```

Your update function may remain unchanged.

Comment: @Kendra: Like you define the `Controller` argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am confused and new to this. How do I do this?

Comment: Kendra, you haven't told anyone what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to make a game of Pong. Should I include all the code from all of my headers and cpps?

Comment: @Kendra why are you trying to dereference a float in statement `*Control()`? Simply use `Control` as a regular function. I.e.: `m_position.y += Control();`. That as far as I can tell, given the code shown.

Comment: When I do that, I get these errors. 1 error C2659: '=' : function as left operand 
2 error C2297: '+=' : illegal, right operand has type 'float *'  game
3 error C2440: '+=' : cannot convert from 'float *' to 'float' 4 IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue 
5 IntelliSense: expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type